# git tracking submodule files from "super project"

Tags: git

I have some large legacy git repository which I divided into modules. My problem is when I try to apply a patch created when we don't use submodule super-project doesn't have the track of submodule files.

Here my steps:

```
$ git clone git@192.168.0.249:super-project
$ cd super-project
$ git clone git@192.168.0.249:my_submodule
$ git submodule add ./my_submodule
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule sync
$ git submodule update
$ git add .gitmodules 
$ git commit -a
$ git am ~/patches/* 

Applying: <PATCH NAME>
error: <PATH TO FILENAME>: does not exist in index
When you have resolved this problem run "git am --resolved".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git am --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop patching run "git am --abort".
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to apply the patches only within the submodules.  If you split the project in such a way that some individual patch files now refer to multiple submodules, then you may need to edit the patch files (possibly by writing a script if there are many).  Or you could try applying the patch files in a "sloppy" way using the `patch` program rather than `git` and ignoring the partial failures which will occur depending on which submodule has which target files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at git-slave to coordinate work that transcends Submodules.

otherwise, just

```
git submodule add url path/you/want
git submodule update --init --recursive
git add -A
git commit -m "added submodule"
```